# Why does emacs indent past a string containing a '%' sign?

Tags: emacs, vhdl, indentation

I am using the VHDL major mode for emacs on a filetype that is custom to my work. Code looks largely like normal VHDL but uses some postprocessing to simplify blocks which are repeated and clean up port maps and IO lists. I use the looping function built in with this that looks something like this

```
%foreach a(0,1,2)
    signal%(a) <= %(a);
%end
```

This generates 3 lines where %(a) is replaced with the number as expected for a for loop in many other languages.

When I use this style I want my indentations for some given multiple line function to look like this

```
my_signal <= (unit%(a) and some_signal) OR
             (unit%(a) and not some_other_signal);
```

But the "intelligent-tab" makes it look like this

```
my_signal <= (unit%(a) and some_signal) OR
                       (unit%(a) and not some_other_signal);
```

This behavior will then compound for additional lines. The Normal VHDL-Mode allows this but when the '%' character is added it will not align with the first chracter after the assignment. I have tried setting custom tab stops and all other setting shtat might affect this to no luck. At this point I would settle for being able to indent to the beginning of any word in the previous line reliably but this functionality seems to be overwritten by the VHDL Major mode.

Does anyone have any idea how I can get this to work?

Comment: Can you replicate the errant behavior under `emacs -Q`? Using `emacs -Q`, I loaded your errant example in to a fresh `vhdl-mode` buffer. Placing the cursor anywhere on the second line and before the first `(`, and hitting `<TAB>` the line re-indented to match the first `(` of the first line. Further presses of `<TAB>` moved the indentation back through the tabstops to the beginning of the line and cycling back around to match the first `(` of the first line.